# how to force OSX to refresh the Text Replace -list after losing it? (still on iOS safe&sound)

Tags: ios, mac, icloud, macos

I use a lot of text replace on iOS + OSX, but today I woke up and my OSX El Capitan has lost it's text replace list. I have about 40 different text replaces there (long urls, bankaccount numbers, addresses etc), and they're on my iPhone but I'm wondering how to force-slam them back onto OSX, without having to copypaste one at a time from my iPhone to iCloud Notes and then to the Settings -> Keyboard -> Text replace?

Also, does anyone know if these are actually on the iCloud at all?

Comment: I'd first be concerned with **why** it vanished. At least run Disk Utility to check the drive. They  should auto-sync over iCloud, try adding a new one to the phone & see what happens.

Comment: @Tetsujin I actually wound up rebooting the machine and logging back on, they were there again. What a weird fix. I wish there was a better method for this, cos it is extremely scary.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the answer seems to be: "Just boot your Mac and log in and see if they come back". And yep, they do. How weird.

Here's to wishing there was a way to press a button and force a reload of the Text Replacement data.